# Json Relative Path

Tags: java, libgdx, relative-path

I use Java and libgdx for my application. I'm currently trying to describe a ui style with a json file, but I must give a path to a texture file. The absolute path is no problem, but how I can use a relative path especially go 2 folders back and then go through a few folders? I tried "../" but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us the code and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go:

```
Gdx.files.internal("Path to project");
```

This will return a `File` that you can then use in your own ways. If you want to access the "root directory", which is the higher "level", put a / before the path, just like this:

```
Gdx.files.internal("/Path/ui.json");
```